# Shell script not running all commands after kill -9

Tags: shell

I am trying to kill a process and upload a file to amazon s3 from one script but It is not working in combination. Moreover, I am getting an output as "Killed" while executing the script. Please find the script below.

```
#!/bin/bash

ps aux  |  grep '[x]yz'  |  awk '{print $2}'  | xargs sudo kill -9 

/usr/local/bin/aws s3 ls
/usr/local/bin/aws s3 cp file.txt s3://bucket-2017-xyz/file.txt
```

The Same script is working if I remove the ps line from it.

Any idea?

Comment: First of all, don't use `-9`; it's a last resort to kill buggy programs. Second, what is the name of your script? It sounds like it is killing itself as part of the first command, before `aws` can run.

Comment: @chepner Yes, You are right. It was killing itself before executing another command, as the name was same as the keyword its grep from the first command. Thank You!